# how to use zend to compress my php scripts?

Tags: php, apache, zend-framework

Well i got a question about zend compress, can i compress a php script then upload it to client server but no 1 can access it only who got some key or something like.

is there a way to do it with zend or any?

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for [Zend Guard](http://www.zend.com/en/products/guard/)